# Why does it take so much time for "Require Password" to get turned on/off?

Tags: ipad, ipados

Settings > [your name] > iTunes & App Store > Password Settings > Require Password (under FREE DOWNLOADS)

This just takes somewhere between a couple of seconds to a lot of seconds to get turned on/off. It's never worked instantly (even a second's delay that is perfectly observable isn't considered to be instant).

Is it [still](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202580/why-does-turn-passcode-off-on-ios-take-so-long) a thing now? I'm on an iPad Gen 7 (2019 version)

Comment: Mostly it’s gone since FaceID removes the entire setting you mention. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: The option appears when you have your face/touch ID off.

Comment: Perhaps it has to replicate that setting to a number of Apple servers?

Comment: @SteveChambers probably a combination of cryptographic key generation and escrow into the Secure Enclave with perhaps a server auth. See my answer, it’s too fast for server response IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a thing anymore (or maybe just means your device is slow, running poorly):

1. FaceID makes this setting go away entirely
2. Turning off FaceID I am able to tap the toggle 6 times in 8 seconds. (Three complete on/off events)

It’s absolutely not instant to enable this as the system has to generate cryptographically secure tokens and store them in the Secure Enclave. Actual work has to be done when you modify this item. From my screen recording, it appears the disable is close to instant and the enable takes the majority of the duty cycle time.

Comment: wait, what's wrong with my device then?

Comment: @charlesh back up the device, restore it entirely, add nothing and retest. Once you’re convinced it’s fast, then restore your backup. Likely a corrupt keychain or runaway process / overall slowness.

Comment: I bought it very recently. There's nothing in there already.

Comment: Could you by any chance show me your screen recording if that doesn't capture anything that's closely personal to you?

Comment: I’ve added an explanation, it’s never instant, but it’s acceptably fast in my experience. There’s more going on behind the scenes than updating the screen content, here. I’ve cropped it, but imgur doesn’t show movies here. Need to convert to gif, perhaps and post process it. You could post your screen recording from your iPad if you want someone to compare @charlesh

Comment: I see. In my case, it took about 8 seconds to toggle twice (One complete on/off event) and then in the next moment, 6 times in 8 seconds.